# Checked checkboxes after form submit

Tags: forms

i have a basic admin form, which shows all content types with checkboxes and save button:

```
function MYMODULE_admin_settings() {
    $types = node_type_get_types();

    $form['content_types'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Content types'),
        '#description' => t('test'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => TRUE,
    );
    foreach ($types AS $typename => $type) {
        $form['content_types'][$typename] = array(
            '#type' => 'checkbox',
            '#title' => $type->name,
        );
        }
        $form['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Submit'),
        );
        return $form;

}
```

When i submit i want to save checked content types somewhere(i don't know what is the best way - save to database or somewhere else like `variable_set`). And the question is how to show checked content types after submit form - `#default_value`. For example if i check `Article` and `Basic page` c.types submit it and save them to `db` i want to see them checked after page reload, how can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most core (and contrib) modules make use of the [`system_settings_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_settings_form/7) function which handily wraps around a form, and saves element values as variables automatically.

```
function MYMODULE_admin_settings() {
  $types = node_type_get_types();

  $form['content_types'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Content types'),
    '#description' => t('test'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  );
  foreach ($types as $typename => $type) {
    $form['content_types']["MYMODULE_settings_$typename"] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => $type->name,,
        '#default_value' => variable_get("MYMODULE_settings_$typename", 0)
    );
  }
  $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);

}
```

You can then grab the value anywhere else in code like this (using the 'page' content type as an example):

```
$val = variable_get('MYMODULE_settings_page');
```

Which is a bit counter-intuitive. You might want to make use of a `checkboxes` type instead, e.g.

```
$options = array();
foreach ($types as $typename => $type) {
  $options[$typename] = $type->name;
}
$form['content_types']['MYMODULE_content_types'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => $type->name,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#default_value' => variable_get('MYMODULE_content_types', array())
);
```

Then you can get an array of all selected content types like this:

```
$selected_types = array_filter(variable_get('MYMODULE_content_types', array()));
```

Comment: yep, i know about `variable_get` really forgot about  `system_settings_form($form);` i read about this before, but forgot. This thing with `checkboxes` really nice. Thanks for answer

Comment: btw, how can i perform some actions on `system_settings_form_submit` ?

Comment: oh nevermind :D, added `$form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_admin_settings_submit';`